# All available variables returning node ID

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to define a custom field in D7 view, and I used views_php.
Here few variables are available as field tokens, but while using it inside the code, it doesn't return its original value, but does the node id.

Available variables:

- $view: The view object.
- $handler: The handler object.
- $static: A variable that can be used to store reusable data per row.
- $row: Contains the retrieved record from the database (e.g. $data->nid).
- $row->nid: Content: Nid
- $row->field_twitter_page: Content: Twitter Page
- $row->field_facebook_page: Content: Facebook Page
- $row->php: Global: PHP
- $data: Contains the retrieved record from the database (e.g. $data->nid).
- $value: Value of this field.

I need to fetch the value of "$row->field_facebook_page";
so I wrote:

```
<a href="<?php print $row->field_facebook_page; ?>"Like</a>
```

When I click on the "Like" link, the given URL is empty. When I print the variable, I get the node ID.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Start with print_r to see what's available:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($data); ?>
</pre>
```

You will likely end up using $data, something like:

```
$data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_facebook_page['und'][0]['value']
```

If that doesn't work, take a look at 
http://drupal.org/node/1140896#comment-5945164

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Keva. It works!

```
<?php 
$node = node_load($row->nid); //loads the entire node values

$fburl = $node->field_facebook_page;
$fburl1=$fburl['und'][0]['value']; 

$twurl = $node->field_twitter_page;
$twurl1=$twurl['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```